# Etiquette regarding adding links to quoted material

Tags: discussion

I often ask questions which quote a sentence from NHK news. I had decided that it wasn't worth adding a link to NHK articles since they would expire in a month's time anyway. I thought that the only reason to do so would be to add more context (but shouldn't that be in the question anyway). But today someone suggested in the comments that I should have added a link.

So, what are peoples thoughts? When is it right to add a link, and for what reasons?

Comment: I'm not sure when it's appropriate to leave out the link, but some websites such as Wikipedia offer a permanent link for the current version of the page, and there are third party services that let you archive the current version of any website. For the Japanese Wikipedia it's called "この版への固定リンク" and the third party services I'm talking about include [archive.is](http://archive.is/) and [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/).

Comment: Personal opinion:  Copying a sentence from any source without reference does not constitute plagiarism if 1) You do not claim the sentence as your own (i.e. not your intellectual property), and 2) Your main point of copying the sentence is to ask about grammar/translation.  That being said, it still probably isn't a bad idea to include a link of some kind just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I really only think links should be included if they are necessary to understand the question, if the content is unreasonable to copy and paste in its entirety, or if the OP/answerer has reason to cite an entire  site rather than a specific section of a page. Using a hyperlink to avoid plagiarism is not really a valid concern in my opinion. People asking questions are not generally going to be accused of claiming ownership or wrongfully profiting from other's work.